# Newton's method check in python

Tags: python, while-loop, newtons-method

So this is my code for Newton's Method using a while loop, z is a complex argument :

```
def which_root_z4(z , n): # function which takes 2 arguments; z and n
    fz = z ** 4 - 1 # defining f(z)
    dfz = 4 * z ** 3 # defining the first derivative of f(z)
    while n > 0:    # this block will continue looping until n = 0
        z = z - fz / dfz #T he Newton-Raphson formula
        return which_root_z4(z, n-1) # after each iteration, the function begins again with the new value of z and n-1
    return z
```

I need to modify it such that it can check whether the function is going to converge or not, by testing to see if the distance to one of the roots is < 0.25.

I have no idea how to do this

The roots of the equation are 1, -1 , i , i

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for convergence by looking at the difference between the current value of z and its previous value. This difference is just the value you add at each iteration, that is, fz / dfz.

I guess you need to stop looping when the difference is less than 0.25, then the code is as follows:

```
def which_root_z4(z , n):  # function which takes 2 arguments; z and n
fz = z ** 4 - 1 # defining f(z)
dfz = 4 * z ** 3 # defining the first derivative of f(z)
while n > 0:    # this block will continue looping until n = 0
    z = z - fz / dfz #T he Newton-Raphson formula

    if abs(fz / dfz)<0.25:  #This ends the loop when z's converged
        break

    return which_root_z4(z, n-1)  # after each iteration, the function begins again with the new value of z and n-1
return z
```

You can also print the value of fz/dfz to check if it's indeed reaching convergence